# IndexOptimize Question

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren, blocking

I have a quick question: Is it safe to run `IndexOptimize` for stats update under `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` to avoid blocking as below?

```
USE [DBA]
GO

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; -- turn it on

EXECUTE [dbo].[IndexOptimize] 
@Databases = 'XYZ', 
@FragmentationLow = NULL, 
@FragmentationMedium = NULL, 
@FragmentationHigh = NULL, 
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL', 
@Indexes = 'XYZ.dbo.XYZ',  
@StatisticsSample = 30, 
@MaxDOP = 8, 
@LogToTable = 'Y';
GO

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; -- turn it off
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### probably not

Ola already uses `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` in the queries that get run to gather data. Adding the outer `SET` statement will not do much of anything.

Though there have been some bugs in SQL Server that result in isolation level hints not being honored, it's not clear from your question if that's what's happening here.

The blocking likely comes from actually updating the statistics, which won't be helped by adding an `UNCOMMITTED` anything to anywhere, because it takes a `Sch-M` lock, which cannot be prevented.